# Unexpected error while compiling Linux kernel 4.4.0

Tags: linux, kernel

During compilation of linux kernel 4.4.0 appears an error:

```
fs/overlayfs/super.c: In function ‘ovl_init’:
fs/overlayfs/super.c:1331:30: error: ‘ovl_v1_fs_type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ret = register_filesystem(&ovl_v1_fs_type);
                          ^
fs/overlayfs/super.c:1331:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
fs/overlayfs/super.c: In function ‘ovl_exit’:
fs/overlayfs/super.c:1344:26: error: ‘ovl_v1_fs_type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
unregister_filesystem(&ovl_v1_fs_type);
                      ^
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target 'fs/overlayfs/super.o' failed
make[4]: *** [fs/overlayfs/super.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:484: recipe for target 'fs/overlayfs' failed
make[3]: *** [fs/overlayfs] Error 2
Makefile:996: recipe for target 'fs' failed
make[2]: *** [fs] Error 2
scripts/package/Makefile:90: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
Makefile:1286: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
```

Additional information:

> Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 OS type:   64-bit
>
> Graphics:  GeForce GT 720M/PCIe/SSE2

```
uname -a
Linux Khumayun 4.15.18 #1 SMP Sat Oct 13 22:05:33 +05 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: 4.4.0 is old, there's no reason for using it.

Comment: actually, the reason I need 4.4.0 is to install CUDA 10.0. Because it only supports 4.4 with Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1493839) in the kernel modified by Ubuntu.

You may either enable `CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS_V1` configuration option, or apply the [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/326997699/patch_launchpad_bug_1493839).

Comment: It seems that it solved the problem, yet another stuff comes.. 

drivers/media/v4l2-core/videodev.ko: final close failed: No space left on device
scripts/Makefile.modpost:125: recipe for target 'drivers/media/v4l2-core/videodev.ko' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/media/v4l2-core/videodev.ko] Error 1
Makefile:1155: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
scripts/package/Makefile:90: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
Makefile:1286: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2

Comment: The message `No space left on device` seems to be self-explanatory - your hard disk is full.

Comment: First, I thought it is not like this, but typing df -h I got sure. That solved the problem. Kernel is compiled. Thank you !